# Tornado https proxy outputs 405 WARNING

Tags: python, https, proxy, tornado

I tried to make proxy server by tornado in Python. The simple http proxy server has worked well, but the https proxy has some problem.
Part of my programs which might have problem are below.

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPRequest
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer

class HTTPSHandler(RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        print self.request.host, self.request.method
        def handle_request(response):
            if response.error and not isinstance(response.error, tornado.httpclient.HTTPError):
                print "Error:", response.error
            else:
                self.write(response.body)
            self.finish(" ")#in case of response.body == None

        request = self.request
        req = HTTPRequest(url=request.uri, method=request.method, 
                          headers=request.headers, body=request.body,
                          allow_nonstandard_methods = True, follow_redirects = False,
                          validate_cert=True)

        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        try:
            http_client.fetch(req, handle_request)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def post(self):
        return self.get()
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def head(self):
        return self.get()
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def delete(self):
        return self.get()
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def patch(self):
        return self.get()
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def put(self):
        return self.get()
    @tornado.web.asynchronous    
    def options(self):
        return self.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app2 = Application([(r"https:.*", HTTPSHandler),])
    httpsServer = HTTPServer(app2, ssl_options = {
            "certfile": "./server.crt",
            "keyfile": "./server.key",
            })
    app2.listen(444)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

It outputs a WARNING like below (when I access to https://www.google.com and https://github.com)

```
WARNING:tornado.access:405 CONNECT www.google.co.jp:443 (127.0.0.1) 0.69ms
WARNING:tornado.access:405 CONNECT github.com:443 (127.0.0.1) 0.58ms
```

Finally, web pages which use https protocol could not be displayed with browser error.

```
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

I guess, this is caused by the tornado’s requestHandler because it does not support CONNECT method.
My question is how can I use the CONNECT method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed the way to fix this problem.

At first, SUPPORTED_METHOD should be written in HTTPSHandler class.
This can solve the 405 WARNING and browser error.

```
class HTTPSHandler(RequestHandler):
    SUPPORTED_METHODS = ("CONNECT", "GET", "HEAD", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "PUT", "OPTIONS")
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
```

This is written in official document as follows.

```
If you want to support more methods than the standard GET/HEAD/POST, you
should override the class variable ``SUPPORTED_METHODS`` in your
`RequestHandler` subclass.
```

Moreover, to handle and process the CONNECT method request, additional method is needed in HTTPSHandler class.

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def connect(self):
    print "some specific processings here"
```

Finally, I took stupid mistakes in regular expressions and ssl_option.

```
app2 = Application([(r"https:.*", HTTPSHandler),]) # not correct
app2 = Application([(r".*", HTTPSHandler),])       # correct
httpServer = HTTPServer(app2)                      # ssl_options is not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to implement the CONNECT method in the same way that WebSocketHandler works, by hijacking the underlying connection's IOStream.  But be warned that this is uncharted territory; the HTTP proxy protocol has some differences from plain HTTP and I don't know how well it will work to implement a proxy on top of a normal application-level HTTP service.